# Set formatoptions for a specific file

Tags: autocmd, filetype

In my `ftplugin/plaintext.vim` script, I have the `formatoptions` set for editing mostly prose:

```
setlocal formatoptions=tcroqan1j
```

However, in very specific instances -- particularly, Python's idiomatic `requirements.txt` file -- I want the format options relaxed. I tried this within the same ftplugin script:

```
" Remove wrapping for Python "requirements.txt" files
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile requirements.txt setlocal formatoptions=croj
```

...but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to have local settings for specific files (based on their name) and, if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in `ftplugin/plaintext.vim` is run when the file type is set, which occurs *after* the file has been opened.

So you are setting up your autocommand *after* the file has already been opened. Thus, the autocommand never fires. If you were to close and reopen the file in the same Vim session you'd find `formatoptions` set correctly.

Easiest fix is to move your line to set up the autocommand into your `vimrc` file.

**Edit**: It occurs to me there might be an *additional* problem even when the autocommand *does* fire: the value it sets might then be overwritten by the code in your ftplugin file: if simply moving the autocommand doesn't fix the issue, you could also try checking the file name in your ftplugin file:

```
" Don't overwrite value set by autocommand
if expand('%:t') != 'requirements.txt'
  setlocal formatoptions=tcroqan1j
endif
```

**Edit 2**: Of course, with the conditional in place, there's not much point in having a separate autocommand!

```
if expand('%:t') == 'requirements.txt'
  setlocal formatoptions=croj
else
  setlocal formatoptions=tcroqan1j
endif
```

I have a nagging feeling there's a more elegant way to implement this, but right now what that solution might be eludes me. Perhaps someone else will provide an alternative answer later on.